# Вызов функции из php-файла

Tags: jquery

Имеется div где выводится фотография:

```
<div class="bigPhoto">
    <a href="#" id="leftPh"></a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('.listPhoto a#343').click();
            });
        </script>
    <img src='путь к фото' />
    <a href="#" id="rightPh"></a>
</div>
```

Фотки выводятся при клике на миниатюры в другом div с класом listPhoto с помощью jquery:

```
$(".listPhoto a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.bigPhoto img').hide().attr('src',$(this).attr('href')).load(function(){
        $(this).fadeIn(600);
    });
});
```

script внутри div.bigPhoto выполняет функцию клика, кот. меняет src у img в div.bigPhoto и при окончании загрузки этого изображения оно плавно показывается.

Проблема в том что автоматическая загрузка фотки не происходит в IE и в Opere (хотя src подставляется), в остальных браузерах всё нормально. Если кликать по миниатюркам всё работает прекрасно во всех браузерах.

Comment: При чем здесь "вызов функции из php-файла"? Почему все стремятся воткнуть этот тег куда ни попадя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эх... `bigPhoto` у вас уникальная на страницу? Если да, юзайте id вместо классов, выборка в jQuery будет происходить быстрее. Или вообще поставить ее на `img`, не на `div` - в функциях ведь именно картинка фигурирует.

Потом. Событие `load` на `bigPhoto` можно навесить единожды - зачем нам каждый раз при клике делать выборку и навешивать его? А для кликов по превьюшкам лучше использовать делегирование.

Как-то так:

```
<div class="bigPhoto">
    <a href="#" id="leftPh"></a>
    <img id="bigPhotoImg" src='photo.jpg' />
    <a href="#" id="rightPh"></a>
</div>
```

Скрипт:

```
// навешиваем `onload` единожды
$('#bigPhotoImg').load(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(600);
});

// или даже #listPhoto, если список один
$('.listPhoto').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('#bitPhotoImg').hide().attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
    return false; // вместо prevent default
});
```

---

Проблема, скорее всего, в том, что картинки загружались быстрее, чем происходило навешивание события. Хотя, фиг его знает, как на самом деле, по идее этот handler в любом случае должен был остаться с прошлого вызова.

Comment: Так вообще всё перестало работать. Уточню: onload должен срабатывать каждый раз когда грузится фотография. Т.е фотка показывается только когда она полностью загрузится. Для этого стоит onload. А в это время показывается индикатор загрузки. Или я что-то не понял?

Comment: Да понятно все. Но объект-то в DOM у нас один и тот же, следовательно, нужды в навешивании по десять раз события `onload` нет - должно срабатывать всякий раз при загрузке новой картинки.

Это - должно работать. Делайте [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), если хотите разобраться

Comment: Довёл код до рабочего состояния. Всё работает, но на live. 
А вот "".on('click', 'a', function() {...""
не работает чё-то.

Comment: А версию jQuery какую юзаете? Для `.on` не меньше 1.7 нужна. Для `.delegate` вроде не меньше 1.4

Comment: Блин, 1.6 !!! Пошёл на сайт скачивать. Так стыдно!

Comment: Не надо ничего качать, юзайте CDN! Так труЪ

Comment: > юзайте id вместо классов, выборка в jQuery будет происходить быстрее
Дак если класс у дива не убрать (нужен для css), почему бы его и не использовать для выборки в jquery, чем добавлять дополнительный id.
Или это всё же быстрее и разумнее (для jquery). (писать и класс и айди у дива)?

Comment: Ну это так, просто хорошая практика. Типа как юзанье для CSS только классов

[Почитайте](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111195/), хотя в большинстве случаев можно на это забить. Преждевременная оптимизация ж